# Make File select "/" go other way

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I seem to be having an issue in a HTA im creating.
I have a HTML file select input;

```
<input type='file' name='txtOpen'><br>
<input type="button" name="Button2" value="Add"/>
```

From this I have a vbscript that pulls the value ( filepath ) which then adds into a database. This all works correctly. Howevever,the format in shown as ( X/X/filename.ext ).
I need the value format to either be in ( x\x\x\x\filename.ext ) or just the file name/ext if that is possible ?

Thanks - James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99s8akf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method to get the file's name and extension, or the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to tumble over the slashes:

```
>> p = "c:\d\e.f"
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFileName(p)
>> WScript.Echo Replace(p, "\", "/")
>>
e.f
c:/d/e.f
```

Comment: Cheers, replace worked like a charm, didnt think about that at all, just have to set the answer as a string and im done with this :)